# Get filtered projects list by applying filters on its fields SharePoint Online CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, filter, odata

How to get filtered projects list by applying filters on its fields SharePoint Online CSOM.(by using OData or something?)

can it be possible using OData?